# What is the Zarisky topology in $GL(V)$ or $Aut(G)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, zariski-topology

I'm currently reading a paper regarding lie groups, and the author says a few words about some set being Zarisky dense in $Aut(G)$ where G is a lie group, or $GL(V)$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, or some subspace of any of them (such as $Ad(H)$ for $H<G$ and $Ad$ the adjoint representation). This is essentialy the same anyways.

I've only encountered Zarisky topology on a vector space (or affine space), but not in the contest of a group such as $Aut(G)$ which isn't a vector space.

Any references/definitions would be great.

Comment: Often in Lie theory you deal with (linear) algebraic groups so it makes sense to speak of zarisky topology: it's just the topology of your group as algebraic variety

Comment: Taking a basis you can regard $GL(V)$ as the basic open set $\{(a_{ij})\in \mathbb{A}^{n^2}(k);\text{det}(a_{ij})\neq 0\}\subset \mathbb{A}^{n^2}(k)$. Now the zariski topology of $GL(V)$ is just the induced topology by the zariski topology in $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}(k)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant function from the vector (affine) space $M_n(K)\to k$ is a polynomial function. So $GL(V)$ or $GL(n)$ is the set-theoretic comlement of the Zariski closed set, defines by the condition det$\,=0$. Open set of Zariski topological space has the induced topology. That is what it is. Same way for closed sets also one can talk of Zariski topology.